# How can I force this NodeJS function to wait until fs.writeFile has completed?

Tags: node.js, async-await

I am implementing https.request per these instructions (https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#httpsrequesturl-options-callback) except instead of doing a stdout, I am writing to file. I want the end to wait until the file writing process is complete.  How can I do this?

```
 process.stdout.write(d);
```

is changed to

```
fs.writeFile(path, d, err => {
   if (err) {
     console.error(err);
   } else {
     console.log("data => " path)
   }            
})
```

This is the entire code

```
const https = require('node:https');

const options = {
  hostname: 'encrypted.google.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/',
  method: 'GET'
};

const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
  console.log('headers:', res.headers);

  res.on('data', (d) => {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });
});

req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});
req.end();
```

UPDATE

MTN posted a solution that works, but I realized that my code is slightly more complex.  I read the file in chunks and save at the end. MTN's solution finishes early.  Here is the code.  Can anyone help me fix it?

```
    const request = https.request(url, (response, error) => {
      if (error) {console.log(error)}
      let data = '';
    
      response.on('data', (chunk) => {
        data = data + chunk.toString();
      });
  
      response.on('end', () => {
        fs.writeFile(path, data, err => {
          if (err) {
            console.error(err);
          } else {
            console.log("data => " path)
          }            
        })
      })
    })
  
    request.on('error', (error) => {
      console.error(error);
    })

    request.end()
  },
```

Comment: What "end" do you want to wait? I mean, what other code should come afterwards? There is nothing in the code you showed that looks like it's supposed to run after the write finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate answer would be that whatever should happen after the file was written would have to go into the callback, after your `console.log`. (There is nothing in your code that looks like it's supposed to run afterwards though.)

---

But:

Your code would be a lot simpler if you'd...

1. Use a library for sending HTTP requests instead of the raw `https` module. (For example: `got`, `axios`, `node-fetch`, ...) - Not only do these take care of things like reading the body for you, they also have a promise interface which allows you to do point 2.
2. Rewrite the code to uses `async`/`await`.

Here is an example with [`got`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got):

```js
import got from 'got'
import { writeFile } from 'fs/promises'

const response = await got('https://encrypted.google.com').text()
await writeFile('test.html', response)

// Whatever should happen after the file was written would simply go here!
```

Note: This has to be an ES6 module because I used top-level `await` and `import`, and `got` doesn't even support CommonJS anymore. So either your `package.json` would have to have `"type": "module"` or the file ending would have to be `mjs`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fs.writeFileSync()` instead. Its sync so it waits for the writing to be finished

Answer (score -1):

```
res.on(“data”, (d) => { fs.writeFile(/* Enter params here */ })
```

Inside the fs.writeFile, add whatever you want to do in the last callback function.

Comment: thank you! I am accepting your answer, because it works for that code, but I realized that my code is slightly more complex. Your solution also finishes early. Can you help me (above)?

Comment: Try putting request.end() inside the fs.writeFile callback. The other events (on error) would still fire when needed ,see if this works